# Hibernate MSSQL datetime2 mapping

Tags: java, sql-server, database, hibernate, datetime2

I have a stored procedure which is returning a column having datatype as datetime2 in database and Date in Java file. When I am trying to call getTime() on that obtained time from database. It's returning 19994321211 millisecond which is equivalent to Mon May 04 00:00:00 IST 2015. ideally it should return milliseconds of 2015-05-04 15:21:52 as this is the time shown in database when procedure is executed directly.

As I am new to Hibernate , I am unable to understand if the issue is related to hibernate mapping or something else I am missing out.

```
<hibernate-mapping>
   <sql-query name="getMLC">
            <return-scalar column="mlcid" type="int" />
            <return-scalar column="completionTime" type="date" />
            { call lsc.MLC_Get(:ABC, :XYZ, :ErrorCode)}
    </sql-query>
</hibernate-mapping>

class Mlc implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer mlcid;
    private Date completionTime;
    // getter and setter
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try registering a new Driver like this:

```
public class DateTime2SQLServerDialect extends SQLServer2008Dialect {

   public DateTime2SQLServerDialect () {
      super();
      registerColumnType(Types.DATE, "datetime2");
   }
}
```

and then use this dialect instead:

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">my.package.DateTime2SQLServerDialect</property>
```

Also try changing this:

```
<return-scalar column="completionTime" type="date" />
```

to this:

```
<return-scalar column="completionTime" type="timestamp" />
```

Comment: I created the class as shown by you and in hibernate.cfg.xml , replace old code with new one as below , but still it's not working . Please help if any other changes are required. <!-- property name="hibernate.dialect">
  org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
 </property-->
 <property name="hibernate.dialect">my.package.DateTime2SQLServerDialect</property>

Answer (score 1):

If you're using entities you can specify the column type as such:

```
@Column(columnDefinition="datetime2")
private Date completionTime;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I am able to solve above scenario by changing datatype as below,driver registrayion is not required:
<hibernate-mapping>
   <sql-query name="getMLC">
            <return-scalar column="mlcid" type="int" />
            <return-scalar column="completionTime" type="timestamp" />
            { call lsc.MLC_Get(:ABC, :XYZ, :ErrorCode)}
    </sql-query>
</hibernate-mapping>

class Mlc implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer mlcid;
    private TimeStamp completionTime;
    // getter and setter
}
```