# add java datatype <-> db datatype mappings

Tags: java, sql-server, jpa, eclipselink

I initially generated the entitis from the database. Now there were certain DB `datatypes` which weren't understoond by eclispelink, such as:

- `DateTime2`
- `Date`

They were just interpreted as `strings`.

Since I am using Java 8 I use LocalDate and LocalDateTime on the java side. And I created a converter from `java.sql.Timestamp` to these to Types. However this only works with the DB datatype `DateTime`, because only `DateTime` is recognized as `timestamp` by eclispelink.

I found **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30028345/hibernate-mssql-datetime2-mapping)** for hibernate.

How to expand the used dialect?

How can I add java datatype <-> db datatype mappings to my eclipselink configuration?

Comment: Eclipselink uses DatabasePlatform subclasses to define database specific field to java types.  See https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/313418/  and bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=458877 has a patch that what was described - you would do something similar for DateTime2 instead.