# JPA entityManager.merge converts LocalDateTime to SQLServer 2012 DATETIME2

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, sql-server-2012

I have a table with a DateTime column as Primary Key:

```
USE [idatest]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DatesTbl](
    [creationDate] [datetime] NOT NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK_DatesTbl] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
    [creationDate] ASC
))
GO
```

When I'm doing entityManager.merge I get duplicate, PK violation since datetime holds 3 digits for milisec, but hibernet converts it to datetime2 , which holds 7 digits for milisec. In the java code, I use LocaDatetime which holds 10 digits for milsec.

I have tried the solution explained at 
[Hibernate MSSQL datetime2 mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30028345/hibernate-mssql-datetime2-mapping]) but it doesn't work :
The java code looks like :
pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-jap-test</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.0.jre8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

DatesTbl class

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class DatesTbl {

    @Column(columnDefinition = "DATETIME", nullable = false)
    @Id
    private LocalDateTime creationDate;
}
```

Main class

```
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Main.class);

        EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = context.getBean(EntityManagerFactory.class);
        final EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        final LocalDateTime creationDate = LocalDateTime.of(2018, 12, 26, 8, 10, 40, 340);
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        final DatesTbl datesTbl = entityManager.merge(new DatesTbl(creationDate));
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();

        System.out.println("test");
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DataSource getDataSource() {

        SQLServerDataSource ds = null;
        try {
            ds = new SQLServerDataSource();
            ds.setServerName("localhost");
            ds.setDatabaseName("idatest");
            ds.setIntegratedSecurity(true);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        return ds;
    }


    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.SQL_SERVER);
        return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
    }


    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean abstractEntityManagerFactoryBean(
            JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter) {

        Properties properties = new Properties();
         properties.setProperty(FORMAT_SQL, String.valueOf(true));
        properties.setProperty(SHOW_SQL, String.valueOf(true));
        properties.setProperty(DIALECT, ModifiedSQLServerDialect.class.getTypeName());
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean =
                new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(getDataSource());
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(properties);
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("enteties");

        return localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
    }


    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(emf);
    }
}


public class ModifiedSQLServerDialect extends SQLServer2012Dialect {


    public ModifiedSQLServerDialect () {
        super();
        registerColumnType(Types.TIMESTAMP, "timestamp");
        registerColumnType(Types.DATE, "timestamp");
        registerColumnType(Types.TIME, "timestamp");
        registerHibernateType(Types.TIMESTAMP, "timestamp");
        registerHibernateType(Types.DATE, "timestamp");
        registerHibernateType(Types.TIME, "timestamp");
    }
}
```

but still I see in the SQLServer profiler :

```
exec sp_executesql N'select datestbl0_.creationDate as creation1_0_0_ from DatesTbl datestbl0_ where datestbl0_.creationDate=@P0        ',N'@P0 `datetime2`','2018-12-26 08:10:40.0000003'
```

What is wrong with the solution ?

Comment: Try to replace `registerColumnType(XXXXX, "timestamp");` to `registerColumnType(XXXXX, "datetime");` as the type should be one of SQL Server column type.

Comment: I have changed it, as you have suggested - same result.

Comment: After some search, it seems to be one issue in mssql-jdbc, checkout [PreparedStatement.setTimestamp(index, timestamp, calendar) has datatype conversion issues.](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/issues/443) for details.

Comment: thanks, @samabcde it is the same issue. The root cause is the mapping of java.sql.Types.TIMESTAMP and microsoft.sql.Types.DATETIME to DATETIME2 when DATETIME2 was introduced.  I have tried to change the schema to be `[creationDate] [datetime](3) NOT NULL` as suggested but still no progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation

The problem is related to an issue in mssql-jdbc (version 4.x and 6.x), [PreparedStatement.setTimestamp(index, timestamp, calendar) has datatype conversion issues](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/issues/443), which always send the `LocalDateTime` parameter with `datetime2` data type to SQL server(ignoring the column type of the table). Due to the different in accuracy of `datetime` (0.00333sec) and `datetime2`(100 nanoseconds), and `datetime` is used as PK, Hibernate works wrongly in this case.

As we run the main program, the `creationDate` is having value **2018-12-26 08:10:40.000000340** and the value is saved as **2018-12-26 08:10:40.000** in DB as Hibernate find no record with same key in DB. When we run the main program again, Hibernate first check if there is any record with same key, using

> 'select datestbl0_.creationDate as creation1_0_0_ from DatesTbl datestbl0_ where datestbl0_.creationDate=@P0        ',N'@P0 'datetime2'','2018-12-26 08:10:40.0000003'

It seems that SQL Server upcast the `datetime` value in the table to `datetime2` for comparison and no record is returned. Hence Hibernate insert the record again, and result in Primary Key Violation.

### Workaround

As suggested by Vlad Mihalcea, it is not a good idea to use a DATETIME column as a PK.
However, suppose we still need the `datetime` column as PK, the following workaround should work. The key to solve this problem is to make the comparison between `datetime` and `datetime2` return true. To achieve this, we can truncate/round the `datetime2` value to the corresponding `datetime` value before passing to DB. The following changes to the main program is tested with SQL Server 2012 Express with no error.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Main.class);

    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = context.getBean(EntityManagerFactory.class);
    final EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

    LocalDateTime creationDate0 = LocalDateTime.of(2018, 12, 26, 8, 10, 40, 341340340);
    LocalDateTime creationDate3 = LocalDateTime.of(2018, 12, 26, 8, 10, 40, 343340340);
    LocalDateTime creationDate7 = LocalDateTime.of(2018, 12, 26, 8, 10, 40, 346670340);
    LocalDateTime creationDate10 = LocalDateTime.of(2018, 12, 26, 8, 10, 40, 349670340);
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    final DatesTbl datesTbl0 = entityManager.merge(new DatesTbl(roundNanoSecForDateTime(creationDate0)));
    final DatesTbl datesTbl3 = entityManager.merge(new DatesTbl(roundNanoSecForDateTime(creationDate3)));
    final DatesTbl datesTbl7 = entityManager.merge(new DatesTbl(roundNanoSecForDateTime(creationDate7)));
    final DatesTbl datesTbl10 = entityManager.merge(new DatesTbl(roundNanoSecForDateTime(creationDate10)));
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    System.out.println("test");
}

private static LocalDateTime roundNanoSecForDateTime(LocalDateTime localDateTime) {
    int nanoSec = localDateTime.getNano();
    // The rounding is based on following results on SQL server 2012 express
    // select cast(cast('2018-12-26 08:10:40.3414999' as datetime2) as datetime);
    // 2018-12-26 08:10:40.340
    // select cast(cast('2018-12-26 08:10:40.3415000' as datetime2) as datetime);
    // select cast(cast('2018-12-26 08:10:40.3444999' as datetime2) as datetime);
    // 2018-12-26 08:10:40.343
    // select cast(cast('2018-12-26 08:10:40.3445000' as datetime2) as datetime);
    // select cast(cast('2018-12-26 08:10:40.3484999' as datetime2) as datetime);
    // 2018-12-26 08:10:40.347
    // select cast(cast('2018-12-26 08:10:40.3485000' as datetime2) as datetime);
    // 2018-12-26 08:10:40.350
    int last7DigitOfNano = nanoSec - (nanoSec / 10000000) * 10000000;
    int roundedNanoSec = 0;
    if (last7DigitOfNano < 1500000) {
        roundedNanoSec = nanoSec - last7DigitOfNano;
    } else if (last7DigitOfNano < 4500000) {
        roundedNanoSec = nanoSec - last7DigitOfNano + 3000000;
    } else if (last7DigitOfNano < 8500000) {
        roundedNanoSec = nanoSec - last7DigitOfNano + 7000000;
    } else {
        roundedNanoSec = nanoSec - last7DigitOfNano + 10000000;
    }
    System.out.println("Before Rounding" + nanoSec);
    System.out.println("After Rounding" + roundedNanoSec);
    return localDateTime.withNano(roundedNanoSec);
}
```

Reference:
1. [DateTime2 vs DateTime in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334143/datetime2-vs-datetime-in-sql-server/1334193)
2. [Date and Time Data Types and Functions (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Thank you very much, the workaround solves the propblem.

Answer (score 2):

I don’t think it’s a good idea to use a `DATETIME` column as a PK. There could be two entities created in the same nanosecond which will conflict.

You should use an IDENTITY column or a SEQUENCE and just index the DATETIME column to speed up queries.

> It is a legacy system - I can't change it. The primary key consists of 2 fields of int and this datetime column.

In this case, you need to use a [`composite identifier`](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-composite-primary-key-with-jpa-and-hibernate/).

Also, I don't think you need these:

```
registerColumnType(Types.TIMESTAMP, "timestamp");
registerColumnType(Types.DATE, "timestamp");
registerColumnType(Types.TIME, "timestamp");

registerHibernateType(Types.TIMESTAMP, "timestamp");
registerHibernateType(Types.DATE, "timestamp");
registerHibernateType(Types.TIME, "timestamp");
```

The SQL Server Dialect should provide the right type of mappings.

Comment: It is a legacy system - I can't change it. The primary key consists of 2 fields of int and this datetime column .

Comment: That's good idea. I have forked the project https://github.com/idaamit/hibernate-test-case-templates.git . I have changed the testcase hibernate-test-case-templates/orm/hibernate-orm-5/src/test/java/org/hibernate/bugs/JPAUnitTestCase.java  and changed the properties file to connect to sqlserver. But it always tries to connect to database h2. Could you please guide me on how to make this testcase to work woth SQLServer